# Image pixel values when converting image to gray are nearly identical (but different) in Java than in Python

Tags: java, python, image-processing

I have the following piece of Python code:

```
def phash(image, hash_size=8, highfreq_factor=4):

   if hash_size < 2:
       raise ValueError("Hash size must be greater than or equal to 2")

   img_size = hash_size * highfreq_factor
   image = image.convert("L")
   pixels = numpy.asarray(image)


input = ImageBase.load_image_from_url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4dCQTBHL36Q/maxresdefault.jpg")
image_hash = phash(Image.open(input), hash_size=16)
```

after performing numpy.asarray(image) I look into pixels and see the following first 5 rows in the 2D array:

```
[226 226 227 ... 234 234 234]
[226 226 227 ... 234 234 234]
[226 226 227 ... 234 234 234]
[226 226 226 ... 234 234 234]
[225 226 226 ... 234 234 234]
```

Now, I try to implement this in Java and expect the same results. I wrote the following method, that is nearly identical to the Python code `image.convert("L")` and is used with the same image (ie, https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4dCQTBHL36Q/maxresdefault.jpg).

```
private BufferedImage convertToGray(BufferedImage pImage)
{
    int width = pImage.getWidth();
    int height = pImage.getHeight();

    int pixel, r,g,b;
    int gray, grayLvl;

    double rr, gg, bb;
    double luminosity;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            pixel = pImage.getRGB(x,y);

            r = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
            g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
            b = (pixel) & 0xFF;

            // normalize and gamma correct
            rr = Math.pow(r / 255.0, 1.1);
            gg = Math.pow(g / 255.0, 1.1);
            bb = Math.pow(b / 255.0, 1.1);

            // calculate luminosity
            luminosity = (0.299 * rr) + (0.587 * gg) + (0.114 * bb);

            // gamma compand and rescale to byte range
            grayLvl = (int) (255.0 * Math.pow(luminosity, 1.0 / 1.1));
            gray = (grayLvl << 16) + (grayLvl << 8) + grayLvl;

            pImage.setRGB(x, y, gray);
        }
    }

    return pImage;
}
```

However, now I get the following pixel values:

```
[226.0 226.0 226.0 ... 235.0 240.0 242.0]
[226.0 226.0 226.0 ... 235.0 238.0 239.0]
[227.0 227.0 227.0 ... 234.0 234.0 235.0]
[227.0 227.0 227.0 ... 233.0 231.0 230.0]
[228.0 228.0 228.0 ... 230.0 228.0 227.0]
```

As you can see, the values are very close to the ones in Python. However, in the subsequent steps I perform additional computations on these values, and eventually the end result in both Python as in Java are significantly different.

Could someone point me out how to achieve the same values in Java as in Python?

**Additionally**
I would like to point out that, before converting the image in either Python and Java, I have looked to the pixel values and here they are exactly the same. So the difference happens during conversion.

**UPDATE - question resolved**
Thanks to the comment of @Piglet, I managed to write everything from scratch using the provided source code.

Comment: Are these conversions and gamma corrections the same? I dont know you have to show what happens in both cases. To check it for yourself you need to print each value in each stage.

Comment: @gpasch I debugged each and every step in the Python .convert method. However, I am not able to go deep enough to see what really happens step by step since PIL Image uses Image.core and as stated in code: 

`# Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface, and should be considered private and subject to change`

Comment: and this doesn't help? why debug Python if you have the source code available? https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/14859ce5068ecfa750097122b61823b44d618892/src/libImaging/Convert.c  ?`